# how to run the cron job in odoo

Tags: cron, odoo

Created the **cron job** for fetching weather information on every 1 minute but it not work. Here, I attach the code (.py function).

```py
    @api.model
    def weather_cron(self):
        weather_location_ids =self.env['weather_location.weather_location'].search([])
        for weather_location_id in weather_location_ids:
            url_cron = weather_location_id.api_address + weather_location_id.name
            json_data = requests.get(url_cron).json()
            formatted_data = json_data['weather'][0]['main']
            formatted_data1 = json_data['main']['temp']
            formatted_data2 = json_data['main']['temp_min']
            formatted_data3 = json_data['main']['temp_max']
            formatted_data4 = json_data['main']['humidity']
            self.env['current_weather.current_weather'].create({
                     'weather_id':weather_location_id.id,
                     'main':formatted_data,
                     'temp':formatted_data1,
                     'temp_min':formatted_data2,
                     'temp_max':formatted_data3,
                     'humidity':formatted_data4,
                })
```

**Cron Job (.xml file):**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record forcecreate="True" id="create_weather_info_cron" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Weather Information</field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
            <field name="active" eval="False" />
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
            <field name="model" eval="'weather_location.weather_location'"/>
            <field name="function" eval="'weather_cron'"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

You made the cron job inactive. Since it is not active this will not trigger the function you wrote. Please change the value to *active* as *True*

```
<field name="active" eval="True"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

All your field are correct add this two:

```xml
    <field name="args" eval="'()'"/>
    <!-- delay the call 2 minutes just to make sure but it's optional -->
    <field name="nextcall" eval="(DateTime.now() + timedelta(minutes=2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')" />
```

Now if the code sill not working you need to make sure of it.

```py
#1- check that your file is in the  __openerp__.py  or __manifest__.py 
#2- if you don't know how to use debug mode in your IDE just use logging to see if Odoo calls your methodname
```

Hope this Helps you

One thing if you used `noupdate="1"` in your xml file odoo will not update the record that it's inserted in first time no matter what you change in the code this will not effect the recrod in database.
just change the id and delete the `ir.cron` record manually from setting menu

EDITS:

every `model with "model.name"` have an `xml_id` like this `model_model_name`
when you see `mode_id` remember to prefix the name with `_model`

```xml
  <field name="model_id" ref="weather_location.model_weather_location"/>
```

and they are in the same module just put `ref="model_weather_location"`

But for `ir.cron` just give the name of the model because it's a `Char` field not `many2one`:

```xml
   <field name="model" eval="'weathe.location'"/>
```

Comment: Now, I got the error in terminal.
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "null value in column "model_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (89, Weather Information, ir.actions.server, null, null, action, 1, 2018-03-23 07:35:58.332089, 1, 2018-03-23 07:35:58.332089, ir_cron, object_write, 5, null, null, # Available variables:
#  - env: Odoo Environment on which the a..., null, null).
" while parsing /home/odoo/Documents/odoo_master/Community/addons/current_weather/views/weather_cron_job.xml:4, near

Comment: At least it's working now and it give an error check my edit you have a mistake in mode_id definection

Comment: Sorry for my syntax error check my edit hope now it will work

Comment: Is your model name 'weather.location'  or what

Comment: No model name is weather_location.weather_location
<record forcecreate="True" id="weather_information_cron" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>       
            <field name="model_id" ref="weather_location.model_weather_location"/>
            <field name="model" eval="'weather_location.weather_location'"/>
            <field name="function" eval="'weather_cron'"/>
            </record>

Comment: what is the name of you model?

Comment: class location(models.Model):
    _name = 'weather_location.weather_location'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167406/discussion-between-cherif-and-user-123).

Comment: After putting <field name="model_id" ref="current_weather.model_weather_location_weather_location" /> it works and give no error but still not creates the record.

Comment: In the terminal it shows: 2018-03-23 10:38:47,630 6728 INFO current_weather_training odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Starting job `Weather Information`. but informations are not created.

Comment: your question was it's not working  now it's working, accept the answer an ask again and provide your logic.

Comment: When not putting the model_id its gives error, after putting it does not give any error but still the code not work.|
I'll show you my .py file and .xml file.
Let us continue this discussion in chat.